# removing duplicated sets from a list in r

Tags: r, list, duplicates

I have a list of vectors, where each vector contains the same number of character strings, e.g.

```
LL <- list(c('A','B'), c('B', 'A'), c('C', 'D'), c('D', 'C'))
```

I would like to remove entries that are duplicated sets, such that the result would be:

```
LL
```

> [[1]]
> [1] "A" "B"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "C" "D"

It does not matter which of the duplicated sets is kept, or if the order of the sets is changed.

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560395/remove-duplicate-tuples-after-sorting-the-tuple-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

may be this

```
unique(lapply(LL, sort))
```